# Outlook email render has issues

Tags: html, node.js, email, outlook, html-email

In my **node js** app I send an email. I take that **html** content from db as a **string** and replace some variables with dynamic values and send it as mail. When the mail comes to **gmail**, it looks perfect. But it's ruined in **outlook**.

This is my html content coming from database.

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="max-width:600px">
         <tbody>
            <tr height="15"></tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <table bgcolor="#007bff" width="100%">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td height="45px" colspan="3"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td width="30"></td>
                           <td style="font-size:24px;color:#ffffff;line-height:1">###emailSubject###</td>
                           <td width="30"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr td height="20px" colspan="3"></tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <table bgcolor="#FAFAFA" width="100%">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr height="15px">
                           <td width="15px" rowspan="5"></td>
                           <td></td>
                           <td width="15px" rowspan="5"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>
                              <table bgcolor="#FAFAFA" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                 <tbody>
                                    <tr height="15px">
                                       <td width="20px" rowspan="5"></td>
                                       <td></td>
                                       <td width="20px" rowspan="3"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td>
                                          <p>Hi team,</p>
                                          <p>Please find below details of the new request for ###widgetTitle###</p>
                                          <p><strong style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold">Customer Name: </strong>###customerName###</p>
                                          <p><strong style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold">Email Address : </strong>###email###</p>
                                          <p><strong style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold">Contact Number: </strong>###contactNumber###</p>
                                          <p><strong style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold">Requirement : </strong>###requirement###</p>
                                          <p>Location</p>
                                          <p><strong style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold">Customer Address : </strong> ###customerAddress###</p>
                                          <p><strong style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold">Longitude : </strong> ###longitude###</p>
                                          <p><strong style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold">Latitude : </strong> ###latitude###</p>
                                          </p></p>
                                          <p>Marketing Agent Details</p>
                                          <p><strong style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold">MA ID : </strong>###maId###</p>
                                          <p><strong style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold">Name : </strong>###fullName###</p>
                                          <p><strong style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold">Contact Number : </strong>###maContact###</p>
                                          <p><strong style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold">Email : </strong>###maEmail###</p>
                                          <p>Contact the  team for more information.</p>
                                          <p><strong style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold">Email address:</strong> sample email (Biz Hrs)</p>
                                          <p><b><i>This is an auto generated email sent by the Project name : do not reply or forward this email. </i></b></p>
                                          <p>Thank You,</p>
                                          <p>Team Project name</p>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr height="30px"></tr>
                                 </tbody>
                              </table>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr height="30px"></tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="15"></tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

This is the mail I got in my gmail.

[image]

This is what I got in my outlook.

[image]

I read about it a little and as I learned this has happened in outlook most of the time. But I couldn't find any solution that works in my case.

How can I solve this? Please help.

Comment: See [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 4):

*The Outlooks* on Windows use Word as a rendering engine. And they're not very good at rendering HTML. There are a few things in your code that are problematic in Outlook:

- `max-width:600px` is only supported since the latest version (Outlook 2019). It is better to set a fixed width (`width:600px`) and add a `max-width:100%`.
- There are straight code errors in your code (like `<tr td height="20px" colspan="3"></tr>`) that would probably make Outlook trippy.
- Using empty cells and rows for spacing is not a good idea. (And I think the values of your `rowspan` is incorrect.) Better use `padding` on a `<td>`.

Here’s a quick rewrite of your code with Outlook in mind.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head></head>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <title>###emailSubject###</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no, date=no, address=no, email=no, url=no" />
   <!--[if mso]>
   <xml>
   <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
      <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
   </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
   </xml>
   <![endif]-->
</head>
<body style="padding:0; margin:0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; text-size-adjust:none; background:#fff;">
   <div lang="en" style="background:#fff;">
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="margin:0 auto; width:600px; max-width:100%;">
         <tr>
            <td style="padding:15px;">
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%; background:#007bff;">
                  <tr>
                     <td style="padding:45px 30px 20px;">
                        <h1 style="margin:0; font:bold 24px/24px sans-serif; color:#fff;">###emailSubject###</h1> 
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </table> 
               <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%; background:#fafafa;">
                  <tr>
                     <td style="padding:30px 35px 50px; font:16px/1.25 sans-serif;">
                        <p>Hi team,</p>
                        <p>Please find below details of the new request for ###widgetTitle###</p>
                        <p><strong style="font-size:12px;">Customer Name: </strong>###customerName###</p>
                        <p><strong style="font-size:12px;">Email Address : </strong>###email###</p>
                        <p><strong style="font-size:12px;">Contact Number: </strong>###contactNumber###</p>
                        <p><strong style="font-size:12px;">Requirement : </strong>###requirement###</p>
                        <p>Location</p>
                        <p><strong style="font-size:12px;">Customer Address : </strong> ###customerAddress###</p>
                        <p><strong style="font-size:12px;">Longitude : </strong> ###longitude###</p>
                        <p><strong style="font-size:12px;">Latitude : </strong> ###latitude###</p>
                        <p>Marketing Agent Details</p>
                        <p><strong style="font-size:12px;">MA ID : </strong>###maId###</p>
                        <p><strong style="font-size:12px;">Name : </strong>###fullName###</p>
                        <p><strong style="font-size:12px;">Contact Number : </strong>###maContact###</p>
                        <p><strong style="font-size:12px;">Email : </strong>###maEmail###</p>
                        <p>Contact the Marketplace team for more information.</p>
                        <p><strong style="font-size:12px;">Email address:</strong> support.marketplace@dialog.lk (Biz Hrs)</p>
                        <p><b><i>This is an auto generated email sent by the Marketplace : do not reply or forward this email. </i></b></p>
                        <p>Thank You,</p>
                        <p>Team Marketplace</p>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </table> 
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to learn more about email coding, I wrote [Email Coding Guidelines](https://github.com/hteumeuleu/email-guidelines) to help you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped me to remove lots of issues. But still I have some content problems

Comment: Could you elaborate with new code samples and screenshots?